# Гибкий скрипт "посещенные страницы"

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

У меня есть задача создать скрипт, который выводит на странице последние посещенные посты. Для начала 4 последних, но будет потребность растянуть его. Потому я хочу создать растягиваемый цикл для заполнения куки, но не знаю как это сделать. Работу с куки я делаю в JQ + плагин [jquery-cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie). Текущий скрипт выглядит, ну кратко говоря никак, но я покажу его на случай если у меня плохое описание:

```
postid=$("#postid").html();
if (( postid==$.cookie('lpost1') )) {
$.cookie('lpost1', 'postid', { expires: 7 });
}
else {
    if (( postid==$.cookie('lpost2') )) {
    $.cookie('lpost2', 'postid', { expires: 7 });
    }
    else {
        if (( postid==$.cookie('lpost3') )) {
        $.cookie('lpost3', 'postid', { expires: 7 });
        }
        else {
            if (( postid==$.cookie('lpost4') )) {
            $.cookie('lpost4', 'postid', { expires: 7 });
            }   
            else {
                $.cookie('lpost4', $.cookie('lpost3'), { expires: 7 });
                $.cookie('lpost3', $.cookie('lpost2'), { expires: 7 });
                $.cookie('lpost2', $.cookie('lpost1'), { expires: 7 });
                $.cookie('lpost1', postid, { expires: 7 });
            }
        }
    }
}
alert($.cookie('lpost1'));
```

Для того что бы сделать гибкий скрипт мне очевидно нужно знать количество куки, которое будет означать количество пробегов по циклу, но length на куки не работает. Как я придумал - можно задавать длину еще через сами куки, тобишь вручную обновлять цифру если мне нужно. Но перед тем как начать я решил узнать мнения экспертов. Идеи?

П.С. сайт на вордпресс, может в нем есть встроенные функции для этого?

Comment: Может .each() может посчитать и пройти по всем этим куки? У меня не получилось, $.cookie не читался...

Comment: а не проще в одной куке хранить массив посещенных страниц?

Comment: @Jean-Claude о таком я еще не думал.. А потом делить str.replace или какой аналог JQ?

Comment: а потом split() и делай что хошь.

Comment: @Jean-Claude в эту же секунду нашел сплит, честно :)  Благодарю.